# Gitlab container registry shows tags with null bytes

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, container-registry

My container registry (gitlab.com) shows to two containers that always have null bytes, no tag id and has been created less than a minute ago. (It does not matter when I log in / refresh the page). If I try to remove them, an error appears

> "Something went wrong on our end."

The registry table looks like this:

```
Tag                                         Tag ID      Size        Created 
c283b7ecd36cead64bb3690a19db96e322722b25    ea3c52324   39.33 MiB   6 minutes ago   
e54f14ea1206df27635d09aef6a304ed5c26ede1                null bytes  less than a minute ago  
ededb73145bf6faef200cbcd49c2d186b47173f2                null bytes  less than a minute ago
```

I can't delete them manually - any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/3031. We may have to manually wipe these Docker tags until there's a better way.